# Bugs in Ubuntu 17.04, looks weird and Nautilus crashes

Tags: nautilus, 17.04, crash, bug-reporting

Guys I upgraded my ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04 and I am having this problem. My desktop icons are missing, nautilus crashes everytime, I cant open the files since the files window is closing after a few seconds and everything looks weird. I had this problem when I upgraded form 16.04 to 16.10 and now I have the same problem in 17.04. How to I rectify this problem?
Thanks in advance

**Edit 1**
I ran nautilus in terminal and I got the error as follows:

```
(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: mkdir failed on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock: Permission denied
net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(nautilus:26501): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/prashant/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
**
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6032:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

[Files window looks weird and closes after a few second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo2pu.png)

[image: Desktop folders missing and nautilus crashes]

[image: dropdown looks weird too]

[image: Error when running nautilus in terminal]

Comment: As a start, can you tell us what theme this is?. It looks like Arc Dark to me. Also, run `nautilus` in the terminal and see if you see any error messages.

Comment: The theme is arc-darker with global dark theme turned ON in the tweak tool.

Comment: I ran nautilus in the terminal but a number of errors came. I got my desktop Icons for like a second but it vanished again. I am pasting some of the errors below.

Comment: Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: mkdir failed on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock: Permission denied
net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

**
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6032:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout)
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Add those errors to your question with proper formatting; it is hard to read them in comments.

Comment: The Arc theme with all its three variants is also available in the Ubuntu repositories (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/arc-theme). Remove your current Arc theme installation first (I don't know how you installed it, so you can figure this out yourself) and then install the Arc theme from the Ubuntu repositories  using `sudo apt install arc-theme`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57598/discussion-between-prashant-kumar-and-edwinksl).

Comment: Is it because of the arc-theme?

Comment: I have a similar issue (`nautilus` crashing) with Arc theme.  Here is the error output in `Terminal`:  `sys:1: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
[Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'nautilus-image-tools'
Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
**
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6032:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout)
Aborted.`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run Nautilus as root you will see the issue is in reading ~Home/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home, and an issue with any theme outside the Gnome clasic. After setting permissions either from terminal or by loading another file manager such as Dolphin, to allow root to read all the files in the contained directory, you might still get the errors that:

** (nautilus:9776): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS

** (nautilus:9776): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS

** (nautilus:9776): WARNING **: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA

** (nautilus:9776): WARNING **: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout ** ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6032:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout) Aborted (core dumped)

After deleting the .config from the ~Home directory and then running Nautilus, it will tell you to remake the directory ~Home/.config/nautilus. That should fix Nautilus. The only thing is that this breaks the ability to edit wallpapers and icons are still unavailable.