# Dropbox bug in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: unity, nautilus, dropbox

This may (or may not) be related to [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908169/bugs-in-ubuntu-17-04-looks-weird-and-nautilus-crashes).

#### General description (synopsis)

When I open the Dropbox folder using the icon located in the Unity Panel, nautilus crashes and my desktop icons disappear.

Ubuntu 17.04, arc-dark theme (however, it happens even after it is removed, so I doubt it's related). Dropbox installed using `sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox`.

#### Detailed description

1. Restart machine.
2. Click on "open Dropbox folder" in the dropdown menu extended from the icon in the Panel.
3. Nautilus crashes (+ desktop icons disappear, obviously).
4. Trying to restart Nautilus does not work until I pkill nautilus and restart it, and get this:

   ```
   $ Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
   Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: mkdir failed on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock: Permission denied
   net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
   Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
   ```
5. After a while, I also get this (repeating every 30 seconds or so).

   ```
   Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy.  
   Please run "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p"   
   and restart Dropbox to fix the problem.
   ```
6. Quitting Dropbox and restarting also gives me this:

   ```
   ~$ dropbox start
   Starting Dropbox...Done!
   ~$ Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it 
   failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: mkdir failed on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock: Permission denied
   net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory 
   Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
   ```

Edit:
So far I tried all the usual suspects, restarting, reinstalling Dropbox etc (and also `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p`)

Comment: Did you "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" and restart Dropbox?

Comment: I did :) Thanks, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot.

Comment: Lets check your file system. Please see my answer and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested. There were not errors, and it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: The only other thing that I can advise is to make sure that you have a backup of the files that were/are in your Dropbox folder (you may have to do this from another computer, or via the Dropbox web page), delete the Dropbox folder, re-create a Dropbox folder, use the Dropbox prefs to point at the new folder, and let it re-sync. Report back.